# I have error while compiling project in Qt

Tags: android, qt, compiler-errors, qt4, qt5

I have project created in Qt4.x and now I'm compiling this project on Qt5.3.1.
The project compiles well for Windows but when compiling for Android I get following error

:-1: error: No rule to make target '........\Softwares\Android-SDK-NDK-ANT\android-ndk-r9d-windows-x86_64\android-ndk-r9d\sources\cxx-stl\gnu-libstdc++\4.8\include\profile\impl\profiler_map_to_unordered_map.h', needed by 'ui_main_window.h'.  Stop

Please help,
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's most probably related to [this bug](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-37113) which is also discussed in [this blog post](http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2014/03/26/qt-weekly-3-qt-for-android-tips-and-tricks/). You are on Windows (first hint) and your NDK path seems quite long (second hint). These facts, combined with the long paths Qt Creator tends to create, generates paths that long to hit OS limits and then strange and cryptic errors can pop out of no where.

Quoting directly the linked post:

> Try installing the NDK directly **in the root with a short directory name**, and have a **shallow directory structure for the project** you are building. If you still have problems, try turning off shadow building, as this appends a long directory name to your path.

Personally I've:

- `C:\AdtBundle\sdk`
- `C:\AdtBundle\ndk9d`
- `C:\Ant`  (a lot of deploy errors occur for a bad decision about `Ant` directory path...)

After setting such simple directory structure I've *never* encountered any strange error due to excessively long/bad paths.